# How to make overlay Vbox nodes clickable?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I'm trying to build a javafx trimmer, I've done it, however when I added a setOnMouseClicked on ImageViews the trimmer I made hides these nodes, so the action is not handled.

I've have set Rectangle -50 in order to overlay the trimmer to the ImageView, unfortunately, this make event not working.

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, -50, 80, 40);
```

the flowing controller builds is frame

[image]

```
package app.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Trimmer2 implements Initializable {
    private Node selectedNode;
    @FXML
    private HBox hboxStream;

    @FXML
    private HBox hboxStreamTrim;

    @FXML
    private Label lblTime;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        buidTrimmer();
    }

    private void buidTrimmer() {
        ImageView pic = null;
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File path = new File(classLoader.getResource("streams/sub_stream").getPath());
        File [] files = path.listFiles();

        Image[] images = new Image[files.length];
        ImageView[] pics = new ImageView[files.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            final Image image = images[i] =
                new Image(files[i].toURI().toString(), 80, 40, false, false);
            pic = pics[i] =
                new ImageView(image);
            pic.setEffect(shadow);
            pic.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) -> {
               System.out.println("do action");
        });
            hbox.getChildren().add(pics[i]);
        }



        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, -50, 80, 40);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 0.5));
        Pane pane = new Pane( rectangle );

        makeSelectable(rectangle, pane);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(); 
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox,pane);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(vbox);
        scrollPane.setId("my_scrollPane");

        hboxStream.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void makeSelectable(Node node, Pane root) {

            node.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (selectedNode != node) {
                    root.getChildren().removeIf(candidate -> candidate instanceof ResizingControl);
                    selectedNode = node;

                    node.toFront();
                    ResizingControl resizingControl = new ResizingControl(node);
                    root.getChildren().add(resizingControl);
                }
                System.out.println("here");
                event.consume();
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to just make a selection of an ImageView inside your HBox? Isn't [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm) a better approach ( of course with horizontal orientation )?

Comment: yes I just want to selection the clicked imageView in the hbox, I think this the problem is with the Vbox overlaying, because when I remove the rect tirmmer setOnMouseClicked works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the Hbox and the rectangle inside your pane, by the way that pane must be empty. hope it helps :)

```
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    rectangle.setFill(Color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 0.35));
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    VBox vbox = new VBox(); 
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(pane);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(hbox,rectangle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events go to the topmost node that is not mouse transparent. Simply set the property to `true` and the mouse events will be handled at the usual node. One additional thing that can make your life easier is the fact that you can also place nodes inside a layout that are not affected by the layout algorithm of the parent and that do not contribute to the size calculations. Simply set `managed` to `false`. This allows you to implement the selection like this:

```
private Node selectedNode;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    HBox container = new HBox();

    File directory = new File("someDirectory");

    Rectangle selection = new Rectangle(80, 40, Color.rgb(100, 100, 255, 0.5));
    selection.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
    selection.setStrokeWidth(4);
    selection.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    selection.setVisible(false);
    selection.setMouseTransparent(true);
    selection.setManaged(false);

    for (File file : directory.listFiles(f -> f.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))) {
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm(), 80, 40, false, false);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        container.getChildren().add(imageView);
        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
            if (selectedNode == imageView) {
                selection.setVisible(false);
                selectedNode = null;
            } else {
                selection.setVisible(true);
                selection.setLayoutX(imageView.getLayoutX());
                selectedNode = imageView;
            }
        });
    }

    container.getChildren().add(selection);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(container), 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Note:** I also removed the use of `getResource` and that is for a good reason. Resources are not guaranteed to be available as files. E.g. if you use a `.jar` file, you won't be able to access them via `File`. Either store outside of the classpath in a directory or make a list of the resources available as text resource to allow you multiple resources without hardcoding every single one of them. (Don't use `File` with the latter approach.)

Comment: this explanation is very important, and bonus note too, I appreciate your help